# Why is OA-7 launching atop an Atlas V?

Tags: launch, spacecraft, low-earth-orbit

After replacing the old refurbished NK33 engines with newer RD-181 engines on Antares, and the successful OA-5 launch with Cygnus to the ISS, why is the next launch of Cygnus occurring on an Atlas V? It seems strange that after investing in new main engines for Antares Orbital just uses an Atlas V instead. Are some Cygnus missions too heavy for Antares?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cygnus is not as volume limited as Dragon or HTV might be. Rather it is mass limited, for the most part.

Thus an Atlas V can launch a more fully loaded Cygnus.

With the loss of Dragon CRS-7, Progress MS-04/65P, and the Cygnus Orb3 missions the ISS is running low on supplies.

They had a recent successful HTV mission, and Dragon CRS-10 missions, which took some of the edge off the supply concerns. But they want to rebuild some of the stockpiles they usually maintain.

Using an Atlas vs Antares booster, Cygnus can take more mass and has the volume for it, to the station.

Comment: To be specific to the "why" part of the question, NASA specifically requested it (as opposed to Orbital-ATK just deciding to so it) because of the additional upmass.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, launching on Atlas V allows about 300 kg more payload.

See [As OA-7 Cygnus moves to Atlas V, high praise noted for Antares RTF](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2016/11/oa-7-atlas-v-high-praise-antares-rtf/) on nasaspaceflight.com